# Htaccess Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am looking to make `www.purchase.example.com` redirect to `purchase.example.com`, below is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.purchase\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://purchase.DOMAIN_NAME/$1 [L,R]
```

I need a variable that will replace *`DOMAIN_NAME`* with simply `purchase.example.com`.

Obviously I can hard code the `purchase.example.com` but I will need the code to work on multiple sites. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your knowledge:

I used a RewriteCond backreference:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.purchase\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://purchase.%1/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this in code, I would do this on the web hosting account.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it a little more generic redirect for every domain starting with `www.`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%0%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```